# Not able to fetch value of isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, custom-directive

Not able to fetch value of isolated scope "check".For testing purpose I'm passing index value to "check". I have to add animation when ng-repeat finishes, But "scope.$last" is also giving undefined value. I'm not to find what is wrong in my code syntax or logic.

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.directive('track',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        scope: { check : "="},
        template:`<div class="routeTable"><table class="table" id="road">
                     <tr ng-repeat="level in levels">
                         <td  ng-repeat="lane in lanes"  check = {{$index}}></td>
                      </tr>
                   </table></div>`,
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.levels = [1,2];
            $scope.lanes= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
        },
        link: function(scope,elem,attr){
            console.log(scope.$last);
            console.log(attr.check);
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.routeTable table tr td{
    border: 1px solid  #000000 !important;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#CACDD0;
    width:30px;
}
.routeTable{
    padding:10px;
    width:500px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <track></track>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="track.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood something. `scope` variable passing only works in the same tag of the directive. In below example I have defined a new directive `d1` which the `check` attribute will be passed into it correctly.

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.directive('track',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        
        template:`<div class="routeTable"><table class="table" id="road">
                     <tr ng-repeat="level in levels">
                         <td  ng-repeat="lane in lanes" d1 check = "$index"></td>
                      </tr>
                   </table></div>`,
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.levels = [1,2];
            $scope.lanes= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
        }
    }
})

.directive('d1', function(){
    return {
        scope: { check : "="},
        link: function(scope,elem,attr){
            console.log(scope.check);
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.routeTable table tr td{
    border: 1px solid  #000000 !important;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#CACDD0;
    width:30px;
}
.routeTable{
    padding:10px;
    width:500px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <track></track>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="track.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank You ..
One more question :  
Making new directive is the only way to get "check" value ?

Comment: No, but I'm not sure of your use case so unable to give advice. Your current example is just using $index, which you can get by looping over the array itself anyway, so it's quite trivial to make a directive to get the value.